# Paypal orders go to complete instead of processing

Tags: paypal

I have written to Paypal, but they won't answer me.

So the problem is that when we receive an order paid with Paypal, some of those go straight to complete, but they used to go to processing.

Magento 1.9.3.9. 
Somebody suggested to change the Paypal settings so that Payment Action would be not **"Sale"** like we have,

but **"Authorize"**, but that would mean we would have to do handwork and 
 log in to Paypal every morning and capture the amounts ourselves.

That's not a solution though. Has anyone else experienced it?